# Magento 1.9 save productname using script

Tags: magento-1.9, script

I try to save the productname, based on the following script.
But I get a TypeError when running the script.

What am I missing here?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(409728);
Mage::register('current_product', $product);
$seotitle = Mage::helper('seo')->getCurrentSeo();
$productnamestring = Mage::getSingleton('seo/object_product')->getTitle();

        $findseo = array('/\h+inch (?:(i[357])-\w+|\h+\w+)?/', '/(\w+)#\w+/', '/(^| )(.{4,}) (.*)\2/', '/\s*-\s*$/');
        $replaceseo = array('" $1', '$1', '$1$2 $3', '');
        $productnamingseo = preg_replace($findseo, $replaceseo, $productnamestring);

if ($product->getAttributeText('active_ice') == ('Ja')):

$product->setName($productnamingseo);
$product->save();

endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use something like :

```
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'name');
```

Instead of product `$product->save()`.

If you have multiple stores, you need to change the attribute for each store if it was modified previously or delete the value for each store to be set to default.